# How to determine the cause of 500 error

Tags: asp.net, .net, reactjs, iis, asp.net-core

I'm using IIS Express and an ASP.NET Core application I made. In my most recent changeset I start getting

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

on the client side. I can'd anything in Event Viewer and the server logs aren't really giving me any useful information either

```
#Date: 2017-04-08 04:24:20
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2017-04-08 04:24:20 ::1 DEBUG / - 60372 - ::1 - - 200 0 64 19049
2017-04-08 04:24:28 ::1 GET / - 60372 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/56.0.2924.87+Safari/537.36 - 200 0 0 23321
2017-04-08 04:24:30 ::1 GET /js/tutorial.jsx - 60372 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/56.0.2924.87+Safari/537.36 http://localhost:60372/ 404 0 0 2764
2017-04-08 04:24:49 ::1 GET /comments - 60372 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/56.0.2924.87+Safari/537.36 - 200 0 0 341
2017-04-08 04:25:02 ::1 GET / - 60372 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/56.0.2924.87+Safari/537.36 - 200 0 0 580
2017-04-08 04:25:02 ::1 GET /js/tutorial.jsx - 60372 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/56.0.2924.87+Safari/537.36 http://localhost:60372/ 404 0 0 1026
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 10.0
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2017-04-08 04:36:21
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2017-04-08 04:36:21 ::1 DEBUG / - 60372 - ::1 - - 200 0 64 20554
2017-04-08 04:36:30 ::1 GET / - 60372 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/56.0.2924.87+Safari/537.36 - 200 0 0 25434
2017-04-08 04:36:34 ::1 GET /js/tutorial.jsx - 60372 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/56.0.2924.87+Safari/537.36 http://localhost:60372/ 404 0 0 3737
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 10.0
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2017-04-08 04:38:28
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2017-04-08 04:38:28 ::1 DEBUG / - 60372 - ::1 - - 200 0 64 9241
2017-04-08 04:38:38 ::1 GET / - 60372 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/56.0.2924.87+Safari/537.36 - 200 0 0 16824
2017-04-08 04:38:43 ::1 GET /js/tutorial.jsx - 60372 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/56.0.2924.87+Safari/537.36 http://localhost:60372/ 200 0 0 6067
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 10.0
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2017-04-08 04:41:07
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2017-04-08 04:41:07 ::1 DEBUG / - 60372 - ::1 - - 200 0 64 27826
2017-04-08 04:41:20 ::1 GET / - 60372 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/56.0.2924.87+Safari/537.36 - 200 0 0 38678
2017-04-08 04:41:34 ::1 GET /js/tutorial.jsx - 60372 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/56.0.2924.87+Safari/537.36 http://localhost:60372/ 200 0 0 12721
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 10.0
#Version: 1.0
```

I've found that if I comment out the `@Url.Content("~/js/tutorial.jsx")` from `Index.cshtml`

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<html>
<head>
    <title>LRC Archive Dashboard</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.2/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.2/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/remarkable/1.7.1/remarkable.min.js"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/js/tutorial.jsx")"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My changeset is https://github.com/jamkin/archivedash/commit/6bde62f9c85d3e8b0e32d1fb83e5737f91050e0e and to me it was working before that.

I've debugged through `Startup.cs` and through my controller (which does get instantiated when I access the page) and there were no exceptions.

Can someone help point me in the direction of the problem?

Comment: It's some server side error (as indicated by the 500 code). I don't have enough information from what you've posted to give you any better information than that. I'd advise adding more logging to the server to see where it's failing.

Comment: This doesn't solve your problem, but you should really be using the built in dependency injection framework that MVC Core provides you.

Comment: Oh, and since you're in MVC Core, consider including your Javascript files like this `<script src="~/js/tutorial.jsx" asp-append-version="true"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

As the error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) " is from client side,Were you able to look at the developer toolbar network tab to see what is the detailed error response from server.

In the IIS log you pasted, I do not see 500 response status. Since you are working with localhost(found it from iis log), server should send detailed error response with stack and other details. Hope you have you have enabled add developer exception page in your Configure method as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling)

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
```

In your client side, You can checkout Developer Toolbar->Network Tab->Click on the 500 Error 
[image: dev toolbar response in IE] .

You can see similar response details in IE/Chrome/Firefox etc